# Copy the first value of field into column header (Access sql)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trying to figure out if I can do this in query and avoid having to use VBA, but I can't find anything from google.

Essentially I have a query that pulls data from a table and formats it using a series of validation checks from a joined table to export to an excel sheet. The query includes two columns that require the first value of the that column to be the column header.

For example: My query currently outputs like this (not all columns):

```
RecordType | RequestType | MarketerDuns | UtilityDun |
 Val Type  |  Val Type2  |  Val Dun1    |  Val Dun2  |
```

And I need it to output like this:

```
RecordType | RequestType |  Val Dun1    |  Val Dun2  |
 Val type  |  Val Type2  |  Val Dun1    |  Val Dun2  |
```

For reference here's my full query that formats it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
"A" AS RecordType, 
"26" AS RequestType, 
tbl_Market.[Market Duns] AS MarketerDunsNumber, 
tbl_Market.[Utility Duns] AS UtilityDunsNumber, 
[Account Number] & IIf([Territory_Code]="CT","-"&[SA No],Null) AS UtilityAccountNumber, 
IIf(IsNull([Account Name]),IIf(IsNull([Company Name]),[Contact Name],[Company Name]),[Account Name]) AS CustomerName, 
Null AS MeterNumber, IIf([AccountName]="1",
UCase(Left([CustomerName],4)),Null) AS NameCode, 
UtilityAccountNumber AS MarketerAccountNumber
FROM ((Request INNER JOIN ServiceAccount ON Request.RequestID = ServiceAccount.RequestID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Market ON ServiceAccount.Utility = tbl_Market.BrokerUtility) 
INNER JOIN CustomerID ON Request.RequestID = CustomerID.CustomerID;
```

Comment: in your desired output are `Val Dun1    |  Val Dun2 ` data or column headers?

Comment: The column header should match the value of the data output in the first row of the query so if the output is 1234 the header should be also be named 1234

Comment: Are you guaranteed to only have 1 record? Either way this is not possible without dynamic SQL which means using VBA. How do yo udo the export to Excel? Can it be handled in that step?

Comment: I was thinking of handling it in the export process as I have some VBA code that exports the query, but I was hoping that this could be achieved using the query. And it won't always yield one record, but the value is always the same in that column, hence why trying to use the first row value

Comment: Sounds like your export step is the way to go because SQL alone will not do it.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for the tips!